# How to add a ReturnValueHandler to an RxJava Spring Boot Micro service

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, rx-java

I have written a Spring Boot micro service using [RxJava](https://github.com/ravindraranwala/SpringBootRxJava). Currently I am subscribing to the `Observable`s inside the controller class. Now I need to use a `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler` as a generic solution to transform between an `Observable` and Spring `DefferredResult`. After going through some resources I implemented the `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler` interface which is given below.

```
public class ObservableReturnValueHandler implements AsyncHandlerMethodReturnValueHandler {
    @Override
    public boolean isAsyncReturnValue(Object returnValue, MethodParameter returnType) {
        return returnValue != null && supportsReturnType(returnType);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsReturnType(MethodParameter returnType) {
        return Observable.class.isAssignableFrom(returnType.getParameterType());
    }

    @Override
    public void handleReturnValue(Object returnValue, MethodParameter returnType, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
            NativeWebRequest webRequest) throws Exception {

        if (returnValue == null) {
            mavContainer.setRequestHandled(true);
            return;
        }

        final Observable<?> observable = Observable.class.cast(returnValue);
        WebAsyncUtils.getAsyncManager(webRequest)
                .startDeferredResultProcessing(new ObservableAdapter<>(observable), mavContainer);
    }

    public class ObservableAdapter<T> extends DeferredResult<T> {
        public ObservableAdapter(Observable<T> observable) {
            observable.subscribe(this::setResult, this::setErrorResult);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I created a `WebConfig` class where I am adding the `ObservableReturnValueHandler` to the handler chain as an interceptor. The code is given below.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.example.*" })
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addReturnValueHandlers(List<HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler> returnValueHandlers) {
        returnValueHandlers.add(new ObservableReturnValueHandler());
    }   
}
```

Now my controller class looks like this.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/currencyconverter")
public class CurrencyResource {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CurrencyConverter.class);

    @Autowired
    private CurrencyConverterService currencyConverterService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/rates", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE })
    public Observable<CurrencyRatesDTO> getCurrencyRates(
            @RequestParam("symbol") Set<String> currencyRates) {
        log.debug("Retrieving currency rates.");
        return currencyConverterService.getCurrencyRates(currencyRates);
    }
}
```

But now when I send that GET request I am getting this error:

```
{ "timestamp": 1485360763263, "status": 404, "error": "Not Found", "message": "No message available", "path": "/api/currencyconverter/rates" }
```

Then I debugged the code and observed that it reaches the `handleReturnValue` method in class `ObservableReturnValueHandler` and the `Observable` is there. A subscription is made to the Observable successfully at the adapter and it returns after setting the response value to the DeferredResult as expected. There's no any `Exception` is thrown here neither in the server log, so I have a hard time trouble shooting this. Wonder what is happening afterwards.What is missing here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should use the method `addReturnValueHandlers` to add handlers and not the way you use it now.

Comment: You are also using Spring Boot, so your configuration is actually competing with Spring Boots auto configuration. Yu are trying to manually configure too much. Remove your current configuration class, create a new one only extending `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` which only overrides the `addReturnValueHandlers` to register the return value handler.

Comment: I tried that, but still the issue remains same. Here is my new code.  @Override
 public void addReturnValueHandlers(List<HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler> returnValueHandlers) {
  returnValueHandlers.add(new ObservableReturnValueHandler());
  super.addReturnValueHandlers(returnValueHandlers);
 }

Comment: Don't add code as comments, edit your question instead.

Comment: Noted and answer was updated.

Comment: I also commented that, due to spring Boot, you don't need `@EnableWebMvc` you are now working around Spring Boot. Which probably explains why your swagger stopped working (no more web autoconfiguration) and you probably also need to enable async processing for the filters/servlets.

Comment: Good, removing that solved swagger ui related issue. But now when I send that GET request I am getting this error: {
  "timestamp": 1485360763263,
  "status": 404,
  "error": "Not Found",
  "message": "No message available",
  "path": "/api/currencyconverter/rates"
}

Comment: Implement the `AsyncHandlerMethodReturnValueHandler` instead of the plain `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler` interface. For inspiration you might want to look at the `DeferredResultMethodReturnValueHandler`